# Two instances not doing automatic load balancing in Quartz scheduler on the same machine

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Two instances in a clustered JobStore are not working on the same machine inspite of having the correct quartz properties (As given in the docs).

The problem seems that the load balancing is not happening and everytime it's the same instance that picks the job (The one that starts later).

============================================================================

## Configure Main Scheduler Properties

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = instance1

============================================================================

## Configure ThreadPool

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool

org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25

org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

============================================================================

## Configure JobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = mySQLDS

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 1000

============================================================================

## Configure Datasources

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz2

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.user = quartz2

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.password = quartz2123

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.maxConnections = 5

org.quartz.dataSource.mySQLDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual

> > The other instance had instance id as instance2.

Comment: Are you sure that both of your Quartz instances have distinct instance IDs? Instance IDs are set using the org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId JVM system property, or you can use the value of AUTO in which case the configured (org.quartz.scheduler.instanceIdGenerator.class) instance ID generator will be used to determine the unique instance ID.

Comment: Yes I have tried setting Instance ID as Instance1 and Instance2 as well as AUTO. But not working. I have tried changing distinct instance names too but still not working.

Comment: OK. Can you please attach your quartz.properties for both Quartz instances? If you provide details on what DB and version you are using, I might be able to send you sample quartz.properties that we use on clusters and that work for us.

Comment: I have added my quartz.properties the only difference between the files for both instances is both having different instanceId. 
I am using Mysql_innoDb and MySql 5.6.17 on Mac OS X

Comment: Strange. We use very similar settings for our MySql-InnoDB setup. I suppose, you will have to use a debugger to step through the Quartz scheduling thread. Sorry.

Comment: @Jan My problem got resolved. I cleaned up all the tables in the quartz database and it started working. But when I am using two instances it is not actually following a random load balancing the instance which took up the job takes it forever until it is terminated. But it looks fine enough. Anyways thanks for you help.